# Weblogic 10, session replication

Tags: weblogic

I am working on session replication with two server instances in a cluster.

Session id is not getting replicated to the second server and hence it always creates a new one, and my open application gets errored out and gets closed. How to handde this failover of server instance so that the user will not be aware if the server instance is down. Here are the settings i am using in weblogic.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

      <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
         <session-descriptor>
       <session-param>
      <param-name>URLRewritingEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
       </session-param>
        <session-param>
        <param-name>PersistentStoreType</param-name>
       <param-value>replicated</param-value>
     </session-param>
     </session-descriptor>

 <context-root>@CONTEXT_ROOT@</context-root>
  </weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Is anything in front of your weblogic instances doing the routing to the instances in the cluster? e.g Apache web server, OHS, a physical load balancer? Can you also clarify -- is your issue that the HTTP Session data does not appear to be replicated between instances or are you seeing that the session id is not being passed back with subsequent requests (causing new session objects to be created)

Comment: Apache Webserver + load balancer. and the session id is not being passed back with subsequent requests (causing new session objects to be created)

Comment: Are you able to test requests to the server where you 1) dont go through the load balancer and 2) dont go through the apache web server (so that you can pinpoint what is causing the session id not be passed back). Recommend using the free tool "FireBug" to examine the request that is being sent to the server. It will tell you if the sesionid is originally being sent with the request. Using that tool and going directly to WebLogic or directly to the Apache WebServer will help tell you if the load balancer or the Apache WebServer is dropping the session id from the request.

Comment: Also, add url-rewriting-enabled (set to true) to weblogic.xml and see if the problem still exists. This will help pinpoint the root cause. See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1062269

Comment: I added urlRewriting flag to weblogic.xml but it didnt help. Also, I tried accessing the application servers directly. Looks like session is not sent back to the next node. I am using Swings Framework.

Comment: I've moved this into an Answer as you can't infinitely comment on something...

Comment: Yahiya-- any luck with this? If so, please update this with the resolution so that others may benefit from the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you know that going to the app server directly does not alleviate appear to alleviate your session id issue, you need to do deeper debugging:

1. Install Firebug in Firefox (https://getfirebug.com/)
2. Go to your website in Firefox
3. Turn on Firebug in Firefox (and make sure that the Firefox's Net tab, which might be grayed-out, is enabled)
4. Log in to your website
5. Look at the Net tab in firebug and expand the plus sign for the request.
6. Look at the Request Headers section -- Do you see anything in the cookie field that looks like the JSESSIONID? If so, does the JSESSIONID stay the same or does it change when you navigate to other pages on your site?

I'm attaching a screenshot of using Firebug to look at the cookie that gets set and re-sent on every request when you have logged in to the weblogic admin console for comparison (rather than ADMINCONSOLESESSION, you'd see JSESSIONID as the cookie key)

[image]

Comment: Just want to check-- you mentioned previously that you were using the "Swings Framework". Are you deploying an applet to weblogic or is it  a Java web app?

Comment: Hi..Its a Java web-app. Also one finding from yesterday was that, eventhough i have two app servers in cluster, the JSession id contains the information about only one server at a time (Current server on which its running.) for ex . lkjdjlsjlfdjkf......!-234234234.  I think it should contain the information of both primary and secondary server. any idea if i am missing some configuration somewhere ?

Comment: How have you configured your weblogic plugin to apache? Can you please paste your weblogic plugin configuration to your original question? I can tell you if you've got it configured correctly or not

Comment: Yahiya-- any luck with this? If so, please update this with the resolution so that others may benefit from the answer. Thanks.